# How to print an entire string (in a cell) by searching the first word of the string in csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

Each rows in my csv file has strings like below. If I search for the first word of the string, then the corresponding string starting from that word must be printed.

```
EQPHHC_10    | 16912      | 0          | 0          | 0          | 53040      | 0          | 544        | 0          | 140643     | 0          | Any message
```

I tried this code. If my search word is "EQPHHC_10", then it must print the entire string which starts from EQPHHC_10.

Desired o/p -

```
EQPHHC_10    | 16912      | 0          | 0          | 0          | 53040      | 0          | 544        | 0          | 140643     | 0          | Any message
```

```py
def find_index(input):
    o = open('PROCESS.csv', 'r') 
    myData = csv.reader(o) 
    index = 0 
    for row in myData:
      if row[0] == input:
        return index 
      else : index+=1
Row_num = find_index('EQPHHC_10')
print Row_num
```

Comment: Please do not use `input` as variable name, as `input` is already built-in Python function. meaning that there will be no way to access that function further in your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just read the file and lines in it. Find the index, print the remaining string.

```
def find_index(input):
    fl = open('PROCESS.csv', 'r').readlines()
    for row in fl:
        if row.startswith(input):
            print row

find_index('EQPHHC_10')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are pretty close. You can use `enumerate` to find the index.

**Ex:**

```
def find_index(input):
    with open('PROCESS.csv') as csv_file:
        reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter="|") 
        for ind, row in enumerate(reader):
            if row[0].strip() == input:
                return ind
    return "N/A"                           #If input is not found. 

Row_num = find_index('EQPHHC_10')
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
import csv
def search_string(input_string):
    file = csv.reader(open('PROCESS.csv', 'r').readlines())
    for line in file:
        if line[0].strip() == input_string:
            print(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could rework your function so it would `return` desired row, for example:

```
def find_row(user_input):
    o = open('PROCESS.csv', 'r') 
    myData = csv.reader(o) 
    for row in myData:
      if row[0] == user_input:
        return row
    return "" #return empty string if nothing was found
Row_content = find_row('EQPHHC_10')
print Row_content
```

Note that it would print first and only first row which fullfills condition, similiar to your original function.

Answer (score 0):

you need to written the row not index. Try this code

```
def find_index(input):
    o = open('PROCESS.csv', 'r') 
    myData = csv.reader(o) 
    index = 0 
    for row in myData:
      if row[1] == input:
        return row 
      else : index+=1
    return "no row found"
row = find_index('EQPHHC_10')
print(row)
```